# Is give an initial value to a member variable valid in a class?

Tags: c++, initialization

I saw an example code in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

```
struct Foo {
    void print_sum(int n1, int n2)
    {
        std::cout << n1+n2 << '\n';
    }
    int data = 10; // ???
};
```

Is give an initial value to a member variable valid in a class? If so, which compiler support it?

Comment: All compilers that support the current C++ standard should support it.

Comment: Even MSVC should now (if you count RC)!

Comment: @chris Do you mean VC2013 RC? I try it in VC2012. Not yet. And is it valid to do it on floating numbers and other objects?

Comment: @PlasmaHH That's a sort of a useless statement, sine there is no compiler which currently supports the C++11 standard completely.

Comment: @JamesKanze, Clang and GCC have the language features down at least, and the library isn't going badly at all now that GCC started on regex.

Comment: @user1899020, Yes, MSVC12, not MSVC11. It wasn't even supported in the preview, only the RC.

Comment: @chris Can I get MSVC12 RC compiler only but still use my visual studio 2012 interface?

Comment: @user1899020, Probably, but I'm not too good at switching around compilers that aren't listed in VS. Extensions are starting to support 2013.

Comment: @JamesKanze: for quite a while now clang claims to support all of c++11, and also gcc claims to do so since 4.8.1. If you want that statement to mean bug-free complete compliance, then likely no compiler will ever support any C++ version.

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this for MSVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx), but the [latest standard](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html) supports it.

Comment: Great article. I fully admin a /facepalm when reading "some C99 Core Language features will be implemented in 2013 RTM". Well at least it didn't take too long to get *some* of the *core* language features from a 14 year old standard. Thanks for making me laugh this early on a Friday morning.